# 4 digit 7 segment & 8 buttons normal keypad on single port (PORTC) of PIC Microcontroller

Tags: microcontroller, pic, hardware

I am using PIC16F882 (28 pins) microcontroller.

I have the hardware in which 4 digit seven segment (common anode & connected by 4 transistor via PORT B1 TO B4) and 8 buttons normal keypad in connected to single PORT pins (PORT C). Now i am able to run 4 digit seven segment without using any buttons. I have to write a code in which when i press a button the display should turn on and show some value.

Now my problem is that, to recognize the keypad i have to set (initialize) the port pins as input and to place value in display i have to set the port (initialize) pins as output. So how can i operate display along with the keypad that are connected to the same port.

I tried to scan keypad and display one by one for 1ms but keypad is not working (controller is not able to recognize a key press). Doing this scanning process when i see the voltage at any key i found floating value of 1.56 V & 2.65 V (Without pressing key) No change in voltage when i press a key.

I don't know what should i do? I need some idea or concept which i can try to implement.
Please Help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Perhaps you might start by drawing us a schematic? You know, a thousand words and all that..

Comment: Definitely need a schematic. You say that the seven segment display is on PORT B and the keypad on PORT C but then say they are on the same port. So which is it?

Answer (score 0):

I think you better use a chip which has more ports for your project (say pic16F877) so that you can have the 7 segment display on 1 port (portB) and the other port (portC) to turn on/off the segment that you like. PortD used for keypad. If you use separate port like I mentioned above, it saves a lot of your time when you have to look at your circuit as well as the code. You can have a look at this link below from Trini Robotics to see how they control the 7 Segment Display:
http://trinirobotics.com/?p=652

Comment: This looks a little like spam, even though I'm pretty sure it isn't. I'd recommend editing to make it clearer that this is a genuine answer, esp by integrating the link as a meaningful reference and tightening up "By doing this, it's very clear and save your time" to be less vague.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I have another go!